# RelativeLayout Cast error with alcatel tablet on android

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int height = size.x / 3;
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) gridview.getLayoutParams();
                int rows = (int) Math.ceil(mAreas.size()/3.0);
                mParams.height = rows * height;
                gridview.setLayoutParams(mParams);
```

Its working fine in any device, but i tried it on a alcatel tablet and for some reason i am getting this error, any suggestion?, it looks like alcatel changed the class for some odd reason and stopped working like the rest of the android distributions?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
        at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1043)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15784)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15784)
        at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1927)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1842)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1339)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1675)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2053)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14252)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14252)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14252)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14252)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14252)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2231)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1995)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1181)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4943)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5413)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/time_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/irrigation_text_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/irrigation_text_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/irrigation_text_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/placeholder"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/irrigation_text_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/irrigation_text_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/irrigation_text_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/duration_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/time_layout">
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/irrigation_text_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/irrigation_text_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/placeholder"/>
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/duration_seek"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="20" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/week"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/duration_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/m"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/monday_short"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/t"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/tuesday_short"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/w"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/wednesday_short"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/th"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/thursday_short"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/f"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/friday_short"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/s"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/saturday_short"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/su"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/sunday_short"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/week"
        android:id="@+id/area_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Manage areas"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_expand"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_expand"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/delete_irrigation_cd"
        android:id="@+id/trash"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/week"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_trash"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
    <GridView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:background="#DBEEFB"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trash"
        android:id="@+id/area_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Managed to fix it, problem was not inside the code i posted, it was in a library class i was using after removing it, it started working fine for every device thanks for all the input tho!

Comment: you want cast **ListView** to **RelatvieLayout** and it's not possible

Comment: @Amir nope i am not doing that at any point, getLayoutParams returns the params of the class of the parent not the grid params, so i am not getting the grid params but the parent view params wich are indeed RelativeLayout (wich is why this work on all the devices i have tested exept this alcatel tablet)

Comment: Whats the parent of the `GridView`?

Comment: @Andy i just added the XML but its indeed a relativelayout

Comment: What is the version of Android that device uses?

Comment: @Andy its Android 4.2.2

Comment: The info you have up doesn't make sense to be honest. Whats the exact line that is causing the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it, problem was not inside the code i posted, it was in a library class i was using after removing it, it started working fine for every device thanks for all the input tho!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you want to cast your LayoutParams to the wrong type, try:

```
AbsListView.LayoutParams mParams = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) gridview.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: Nope, thats plain wrong, it needs to be casted to the parent layoutParams, not to a random Params, i tried this anyway b4 posting but as i expected i got an error

Comment: @Andy sory if it did not sound nice, i dont speak english natively.